# Conductor of determinant of a 2-dimensional Galois representation divides conductor of representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, characters

I am studying [Serre's paper "Sur les représentations modulaires de degré 2 de $\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}$"](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL5835292064138487263_Serre_Repr.modulaires_Galois.pdf) and I'm stuck trying to prove that $N(\det\rho)$ divides $N(\rho)$.

For context, consider a 2-dimensional Galois representation

$$\rho:\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}\to \mathrm{GL}(V),$$
where $V$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Denote $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\cong\mathrm{Im}(\rho)$. We define the conductor of $\rho$ as

$$ N(\rho)=\prod_{\ell\neq p\text{ prime}}\ell^{n(\ell,\rho)},\quad \text{ where }\quad n(\ell,\rho)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{[G_0:G_i]}\dim(V/V_i), $$

and $G_i$ denotes the $i$-th ramification group of $G$, and

$$V_i=\{v\in V:\rho(\sigma)v=v\text{ for all }\sigma\in G_i\}. $$

We can also consider the homomorphism
$$ \det\rho:\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}\to \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^\times$$
as a 1-dimensional representation and associate its conductor.

I want to prove that $N(\det\rho)$ divides $N(\rho)$, which happens if and only if $n(\ell,\det\rho)\leq n(\ell,\rho)$. Since $\dim V=2$ and $\dim\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p=1$, the only case in which this is not clear is when $\dim{V_i}=2$; i.e., $V_i=V$.

Let $U=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, and define
$$ U_i = \{u\in U:\det\rho(\sigma)u=u\text{ for all }\sigma\in H_i\},$$
where $H_i$ is the $i$-th ramification group of $H\cong\mathrm{Im}(\det\rho)$.

We need to see that $U_i = U$ as well. But I have trouble proving the statement because I don't understand how the groups $G_i$ and $H_i$ are related. I'm not even sure if Serre is considering these ramification groups defined locally or globally.

I'm aware this is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217469/artin-conductor-of-a-character-and-factorisation-through-mathbbz-n-mathbb) and I'm aware that we can use the Kronecker-Webber theorem and CFT to prove it. But I'm trying to do it just as Serre suggest in his paper, comparing formulas of $N(\rho)$ and $N(\det\rho)$. If someone can give me a hint I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe ramification groups are always defined locally, never globally: They are defined as subgroups of the Galois group of some local field, via restrictions on how elements of the Galois group act on a uniformizer of a local field extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address your question about the relationship between $G_i$ and $H_i$, by giving a slightly different definition of the conductor. Let $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ be *any* finite Galois group through which $\rho$ factors (in your question, you restrict $G$ to be the image of $\rho$). Then, just as with your definition, we can examine the decomposition group at a prime over $\ell$ and its ramification groups $G_i$, and define the conductor exponent to be
$$ n(\ell,\rho) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{[G_0:G_i]}\dim(V/V_i).$$
Importantly, this number is independent of which $G$ we choose. This fact is a consequence of [Herbrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group#Herbrand%27s_theorem), since the formula for $n(\ell,\rho)$ is equivalent to $\int_0^\infty \dim(V/V^x)\,dx$, where $V^x$ is the invariant subspace of the ramification group $G^x$, using upper numbering.

With this adjustment, the inequality $n(\ell,\det\rho)\leq n(\ell,\rho)$ becomes much more straightforward. As you noted, the proof reduces to showing that $V_i=V$ implies that $U_i=U$. But now, with this adjusted definition, we can take the groups $G_i$ and $H_i$ to be the same. The claim then follows because the determinant of a representation of $G$, on which $G_i$ acts trivially, is the identity on $G_i$.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your detailed answer. It was really helpful and made me aware or the importance of higher ramification groups in upper numbering! +1